# Delete all text on a line after specified text is found

Tags: regex

I am using a program called TextCrawler Pro which allows me to run as a macro.

I'd like to clean up a weather page on a daily basis to go from this:

```
Billings, MT;93;62;80;53;Not as warm;NNE;10;44%;20%;8

Birmingham, AL;80;70;81;69;Thunderstorms;SSW;6;81%;90%;4

Bismarck, ND;92;57;92;63;Mostly sunny;SE;12;46%;36%;8

Boise, ID;85;51;77;49;Mostly sunny, nice;N;8;36%;0%;8
```

to this:

```
Billings, MT;93;62;80;53;

Birmingham, AL;80;70;81;69;

Bismarck, ND;92;57;92;63;

Boise, ID;85;51;77;49;
```

I can find using `\;\d+\;\d+\;\d+\;\d+\;` but I can't delete to the end of the line.

I tried adding `\r\n` to the end of the above like this: `\;\d+\;\d+\;\d+\;\d+\;\r\n`

but that replaces all my City information with the actual regex code.

Any ideas? I feel like I'm missing something very simple.

Comment: `cut -d\; -f1-5 < input.txt > output.txt` should do the job... No reason to complicate things with regexes...

Comment: thanks, this is on a windows server though not sure how to run that?

Comment: What language are you doing this in?

Comment: I am using a program called TextCrawler Pro which allows me to run as a macro. https://www.digitalvolcano.co.uk

Answer (score 0):

```
(.*\,\s[A-Z]+;\d{2};\d{2};\d{2};\d{2};)(.+)
```

The first group is what you're after, ignore the second.
[See it here](https://regex101.com/r/ZW5m1T/1)

Comment: Awesome so how could I delete group 2 from the text?

Answer (score 0):

There will be many, many different patterns that will successfully remove the unwanted substrings for you.  Here are a few that I've cooked up.  ([Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aN0y9X/1))

> 67 steps `^([^;]+;[^;]+;[^;]+;[^;]+;[^;]+;).*$`  #most efficient pattern in my list

91 steps `^((?:[^;]+;){5}).*$`

127 steps `(.+?;.+?;.+?;.+?;.+?;).*`

157 steps `((?:.+?;){5}).*`

163 steps `(.+?;)[^\d].*`

185 steps `(.+\d{2};)[A-Z].*`

280 steps `(.*\,\s[A-Z]+;\d{2};\d{2};\d{2};\d{2};)(.+)`

The way that you remove the unwanted part, is by replacing the full line with just the wanted part.

Referencing these document pages:

https://www.digitalvolcano.co.uk/textcrawlermanual/regular_expression_reference_guide.htm

https://www.digitalvolcano.co.uk/textcrawlermanual/regular_expression_find_replace.htm

> You should be able to just use `$1` as the replacement value and everything will be cleaned up.